# How to combine results from multiple imputed categorical data

Tags: categorical-data, chi-squared-test, multiple-imputation

I would like to combine the results from multiple imputed categorical data to compare with the results from the original data. I know how to combine results from multiple imputation of dichotomuous and continuous data (coefficient resp. odds ratio, standard errors and p-values). I also know how to pool $\chi^2$-values from a $\chi^2$-test to compute a pooled p-value ([Li 1991](http://www3.stat.sinica.edu.tw/statistica/oldpdf/A1n15.pdf)). But how should I pool the cross tables respectively percentages of each level (2xn-level cross table)? Should I just average the single cell of each multiple imputation, respectivly the percentages of each level?

Update 1: To have an idea about the data, I created a table:

```
df0 <- expand.grid(group    = c("ctrl","treat")
                   , levels = LETTERS[1:4]
)
df0$n <- round(runif(8,3,20),0)
df1 <- reshape(df0, idvar = "levels", timevar="group", direction="wide")
df1$p.ctrl <- round(with(df1, n.ctrl/sum(n.ctrl)),2)
df1$p.treat <- round(with(df1, n.treat/sum(n.treat)),2)
df1
  levels n.ctrl n.treat p.ctrl p.treat
1      A     18      17   0.30    0.25
3      B      8      17   0.13    0.25
5      C     18      18   0.30    0.26
7      D     16      16   0.27    0.24
```

This could be the original data with total $N$ observation. Now, imagine 10 such tables from multiple imputation with each $N_1=N_2= ... =N_{10} > N$.

Comment: Can you simply recast your procedure as an OLS regression on dummy variables, and follow standard MI practice from there?

Comment: @generic_user: I don't think so since the outcome is a categorical variable and the indipendent variable is categorical with two levels.

Comment: Oh I thought that your X's were the categoricals. I still don't understand what kind of analysis you're doing.  Could you cast it as a multinomial logit?

Comment: @generic_user Thanks for this suggestion. I also thought to use multinomial regression but the problem is that in our field nobody would understand it. So, I prefer to use classical, old fashioned $\chi^2$-test.

Comment: I arrived to the conclusion to sum up all 10 tables and dividing by 10: $a_{ij} = \frac{1}{10}\sum_1^{10} a_{ijk}$ where $i$ and $j$ are the row and column index and $k$ is the table index. I get a combination of 10 multiple imputed table which I can compare with the original distribution.

Comment: Using the pooling method I presented above has the inconvience that after rounding the sum of the column may be larger or smaller than all participant without drop outs. This is due to rounding. Is there a way to cope with that?